# jsViews - error, while using data-link

Tags: javascript, jsrender, jsviews

I have the following script template:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input data-link="FirstName" type="text" />
    </div>


    <button>Search</button>
</script>
```

I fire jsView with the following command:

```
$.templates("#template").link("#result", model);
```

Where model is js object

```
function myModel() {
    this.FirstName = "";
}
```

Unfortunately, `link` command casues error:

```
TypeError: elem.dispatchEvent is not a function
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: use jquery [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode

Comment: I've tried, but it didn't help. The same error were throwed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be the way you are constructing your model?

For instance, this doesn't work ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/VbEbh/)):

```
function myModel() {
    this.FirstName = "",
}
var model = myModel();
$.templates("#template").link("#result", model);
```

But this works ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/GNMM6/)):

```
var model= {
    FirstName : "",
}

$.templates("#template").link("#result", model);
```

As does this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/67teD/)):

```
function myModel() {
    this.FirstName = "",
}
var model = new myModel(); //<---the new keyword makes the difference
$.templates("#template").link("#result", model);
```

Comment: Well.. Actually model is got from $.ajax success function. It could be a Solution, but I'd like to avoid rewritng data from ajax callback to custom class.

Comment: Are you using prototype.js in your page?

Comment: No. Only jQUery and jsView.

Comment: Any chance you can reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: "TypeError: elem.dispatchEvent is not a function" doesn't sound like it is happening within JsViews. You'd at least need a fiddle, for us to be able to help you out...

Comment: Yeah, but When I remove link function, everything workds. I'll try to reproduce it in a fiddle later.

Comment: I'm feeling the same way as @BorisMoore. When I looked at the lib code, I didn't see anything throwing a "TypeError: elem.dispatchEvent is not a function" exception. It's prob a browser thing or the result of some lib conflict (something bulldozing something else, perhaps).